# Catching wcf-exceptions on iPhone with MonoTouch

Tags: ios, wcf, xamarin.ios

i've been running into problems with exceptions thrown on the server and catching them on the client (iPhone).

The interface of the service has a method declared with the

```
[FaultContract(typeof(SecurityException))]
```

In the method I throw a SecurityException. On the phone I get the following error:

```
{System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure 
---> System.IO.IOException: EndRead failure 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer   
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (IAsyncResult result) [0x0002d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs:1979
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar) [0x0002f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:338    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar) [0x0003d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:340    
at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone (IAsyncResult result) [0x0002a] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:429    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:852
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.GotResponse (IAsyncResult result) [0x0001f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/HttpRequestChannel.cs:218 }
```

Now I browsed through the questions about this, and it seems that this bug was reported already and fixed in a version of monotouch. I am using the latest (6.0.4) version of monotouch, but still experience the error.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should create a test case and file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com - it's hard to say what's going on here without being able to run the app myself.

Comment: Hello, after more research it turned out that SecurityException was the problem. Throwing a FaultContract(typeof(string)) works just fine and basically fixes my problem.

Comment: Did you decorate your `SecurityException` with `[DataContract]` ?